# Why keeps my $_FILES empty when I post data in objective-c to server?

Tags: php, objective-c, post

I am trying to POST one piece of text to a server, but without any luck so far.
What I do is use the code below to POST the string to the server.
To test if the server is getting any data I use the following:

```
<?php
     print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

**TO POST THE STRING:**

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://[webaddress]/[page].php"]];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",@"test"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n",@"testvalue"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
           [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
           NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
```

In my test environment I use the real address, but for security I removed it.
I use NSLog to give back the result of the server (used within the NSURLConnection delegate).
But my problem is that the $_FILES keeps getting back empty?
The strange thing is that when using the following with a image it does give me something back:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://[webaddress]/[page].php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // setting the body of the post to the request

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
     connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
```

So to upload the image (last piece of code) the $_FILES is not empty and when using the first piece of code it is empty.
The server is working normal and the file used to give back the $_FILES is just a normal PHP file.
PHP is working and the fact that the image can be uploaded gives me the idea that there is a bug in the first piece of the code and not the server.

**So my  question is why is the $_FILES empty when I upload a normal string?**

Comment: By the way, do not call `start` with `initWithRequest` unless you use the rendition with `startImmediately` set to `NO`. You are, in effect, starting the connection twice. Remove the call to `start`. See the documentation for the `start` method for more info.

Comment: That's right, I was getting frustated that I wasn't getting an good answer from the server. So I tried to explicitly start the connection, but I should have set the init to NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File data/info will be in `$_FILES` and posted form data (strings) will be in `$_POST` or if you use get method data will be in `$_GET`.

Comment: Could somebody please hit me! You are absolute right when uploading an image there is a file so $_FILES will not be empty and when uploading just text it will be in $_POST. Thanks, another noob question answered ;)